# How to open the preference page in right click with specific items?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I want to right click the 'preference' menu and get the pref page opened filtered with only specific tree items which I define.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the `createPreferenceDialogOn` methods of `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil` to show a limited set of preference pages